# Adding functions to p-queue to handle concurrency stops queue

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I am using [p-queue](https://github.com/sindresorhus/p-queue) with Puppeteer. The goal is to run an X amount of Chrome instances where p-queue limits the amount of concurrency. When an exception occurs within a task in queue, I would like to requeue it. But when I do that the queue stops.

I have the following:

getAccounts it simply a helper method to parse a JSON file. And for every entry, I create it a task and submit it to the queue.

```
    async init() {
        let accounts = await this.getAccounts();
        accounts.map(async () => {
            await queue.add(() => this.test());
        });
        await queue.onIdle();
        console.log("ended, with count: " + this._count)
    }
```

The test method:

```
    async test() {
        this._count++;
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
        try {
            const page = await browser.newPage();
            await page.goto(this._url);

            if (Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) > 4) {
                throw new Error("Simulate error");
            }

            await browser.close();
        } catch (error) {
            await browser.close();
            await queue.add(() => this.test());
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
```

If I run this without `await queue.add(() => this.test());`, it runs fine and limits the concurrency to 3. But with it, whenever it goes in the catch, the current Chrome instance stops.

It also does not log the error, and neither this `console.log("ended, with count: " + this._count)`.

Is this a bug with the node module, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend checking [Apify SDK package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/apify), where you can simply use one of helper class to manage puppeteer pages/browsers.

[PuppeteerPool](https://sdk.apify.com/docs/api/puppeteerpool):
It manages browser instances for you. If you set one-page per browser. Each new page will create a new browser instance.

```
const puppeteerPool = new PuppeteerPool({
    maxOpenPagesPerInstance: 1,
});

const page1 = await puppeteerPool.newPage();
const page2 = await puppeteerPool.newPage();
const page3 = await puppeteerPool.newPage();

// ... do something with the pages ...

// Close all browsers.
await puppeteerPool.destroy();
```

Or the [PuppeteerCrawler](https://sdk.apify.com/docs/api/puppeteercrawler) is more powerfull with several options and helpers. You can manage the whole crawler in puppeteer there. You can check the [PuppeteerCrawler example](https://sdk.apify.com/docs/examples/puppeteercrawler).

edit:
Example of using PuppeteerCrawler 10 concurency

```
const Apify = require('apify');

Apify.main(async () => {
    // Apify.openRequestQueue() is a factory to get a preconfigured RequestQueue instance.
    // We add our first request to it - the initial page the crawler will visit.
    const requestQueue = await Apify.openRequestQueue();
    await requestQueue.addRequest({ url: 'https://news.ycombinator.com/' }); // Adds URLs you want to process

    // Create an instance of the PuppeteerCrawler class - a crawler
    // that automatically loads the URLs in headless Chrome / Puppeteer.
    const crawler = new Apify.PuppeteerCrawler({
        requestQueue,
        maxConcurrency: 10, // Set max concurrency
        puppeteerPoolOptions: {
            maxOpenPagesPerInstance: 1, // Set up just one page for one browser instance
        },
        // The function accepts a single parameter, which is an object with the following fields:
        // - request: an instance of the Request class with information such as URL and HTTP method
        // - page: Puppeteer's Page object (see https://pptr.dev/#show=api-class-page)
        handlePageFunction: async ({ request, page }) => {
            // Code you want to process on each page
        },

        // This function is called if the page processing failed more than maxRequestRetries+1 times.
        handleFailedRequestFunction: async ({ request }) => {
            // Code you want to process when handlePageFunction failed
        },
    });

    // Run the crawler and wait for it to finish.
    await crawler.run();

    console.log('Crawler finished.');
});
```

Example of using RequestList:

```
const Apify = require('apify');

Apify.main(async () => {
    const requestList = new Apify.RequestList({
        sources: [
            // Separate requests
            { url: 'http://www.example.com/page-1' },
            { url: 'http://www.example.com/page-2' },
            // Bulk load of URLs from file `http://www.example.com/my-url-list.txt`
            { requestsFromUrl: 'http://www.example.com/my-url-list.txt', userData: { isFromUrl: true } },
        ],
        persistStateKey: 'my-state',
        persistSourcesKey: 'my-sources',
    });

    // This call loads and parses the URLs from the remote file.
    await requestList.initialize();
    const crawler = new Apify.PuppeteerCrawler({
        requestList,
        maxConcurrency: 10, // Set max concurrency
        puppeteerPoolOptions: {
            maxOpenPagesPerInstance: 1, // Set up just one page for one browser instance
        },
        // The function accepts a single parameter, which is an object with the following fields:
        // - request: an instance of the Request class with information such as URL and HTTP method
        // - page: Puppeteer's Page object (see https://pptr.dev/#show=api-class-page)
        handlePageFunction: async ({ request, page }) => {
            // Code you want to process on each page
        },

        // This function is called if the page processing failed more than maxRequestRetries+1 times.
        handleFailedRequestFunction: async ({ request }) => {
            // Code you want to process when handlePageFunction failed
        },
    });

    // Run the crawler and wait for it to finish.
    await crawler.run();

    console.log('Crawler finished.');
});
```

Comment: What about my use case? Let's say I would need to run 500 instances, with a concurrency limit of 10 instances async. How would this package help? Or how could I achieve that using this SDK? Thanks a ton!

Comment: I added an example for your case in the post.

Comment: I see, thanks. So to "queue" the 500 instances for my usecase, I would add the URL's to the request queue? Eg: `accounts.map(async () => {
                await requestQueue.addRequest({ url: this._url });
            });`

Edit: how would it work when an exception is thrown, and I would like that request to requeue?

Comment: It should work, but if you have just list of URLs and you do not need to enqueue new during crawling, it is better to use Request list. https://sdk.apify.com/docs/api/requestlist. I added example to the post.

Comment: It works on my local env. 
About exception, you can handle exception in handleFailedRequestFunction, but a request will be retried 4 times if it fails you can set up the number of retries in options. maxRequestRetries.